# Rental expenses in Canada, current vs capital

Tags: canada, rental-property, capital-expenditure

I am renting my house in Ontario Canada, and claiming the rental income/expenses on my tax return. I know I can claim current repair expenses, but next year 2024, I have to replace the roof and carpets in the rental house. Can I claim these expenses as current or do I have to treat them as capital expenditures? I prefer not to claim any capital cost allowance, because I intend to move into the house in the future as my principal residence. If capital expenses, then I will add the expenses to my adjusted cost base when selling in the future.

Comment: I also read that I can claim the new dishwasher I purchased to replace the old one as a current expense.

Comment: This is a question that contains a higher level of subjective judgment. See here: https://realestatetaxtips.ca/new-roof-one-time-write-off-depreciable-expense/#:~:text=Even%20though%20a%20roof%20does,deductible%20against%20future%20sale%20price. [note: I have no relation to the site, and have done only a brief review of the material; it seems sound to me]